# Getting average value of a column in GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I fetch data by grouping referers, and in every referer, I try to get the average clicks on every referer. For example:

```
referer a site
--------------
avg clicks: 12


referer b site
--------------
avg clicks: 4
```

I use this code

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*)
FROM track
GROUP BY referer
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 15    

while ($yazdir=mysql_fetch_array($sqlsorgu))
{
    $count = $yazdir['COUNT(*)'];
    $clicks[] = $yazdir[clicks];
    $score_sum = array_sum($clicks);
    $mean_average = $score_sum / $count;
}
```

However, it always calculates wrong numbers, maybe it stores previous ones also. What is the correct way to get the average clicks on every referer ?

Comment: there's an AVG() function in mysql...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not

```
    SELECT *, COUNT(*),AVG(clicks)  
   FROM track GROUP BY referer ORDER BY id desc limit 15
```